# How to handle NewOrderList in an ExecutionReport

Tags: quickfixj

Hi i am new to fix protocols, i was wondering how to process a NewOrderList from an ExecutionReport. As per a fix message document on the internet `https://gainfutures.com/api/html/133e2886-5411-44b7-b781-2311a45ab540.htm` i came to know that every order in the NewOrderList will be processed one at a time in the ExecutionReport.

From the above doc:
`order statuses and trades are reported for individual orders, not for the list as whole`.

Is there a way i can get the list of order details back from the ExecutionReport event listener using below

```java
public void onMessage(ExecutionReport report, SessionID sessionID) {
        // handler implementation
}
```

Comment: I read "order statuses and trades are reported for individual orders, not for the list as whole" as: for each order status or trade you will get a distinct ExecutionReport message. So you will not get a list of executions in one message but in several. Or did I misunderstand your question? Maybe you can clarify.

Comment: From the link. `Validation of the list is performed as a single transaction. That means if, for example, one of orders is invalid then all orders in the list will be rejected. Further processing is performed individually for each order: order statuses and trades are reported for individual orders, not for the list as whole.` So 1 ER for one executed order. So no you cannot get a list of ERs, it has to be one by one.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help :)